# Are portable .exe's possible in .NET Core?

Tags: .net-core, exe, portable-applications

I recently went though learning about the "publish" concept that is in .NET core (because my build was outputting dll for a console app, not an exe). So then I read through the framework dependent vs self contained deployments.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/index

When I think of "portable" applications, I think all you need is the exe, but even with the Self Contained Deployment, you still need the entire folder.

(I tried moving just the .exe to another folder and then running it, but it said it was missing hostfxr.dll, then I moved its entire folder with all the dll's and it worked fine)

So the user can copy paste an entire folder, but a folder is not executable, they have to go in and click on the .exe, but then they probably are like me and will just move the .exe to where ever they want, and it will stop working :(

**So how can I get the user to click on the only thing they need to copy paste and have the program run?** (Like we used to be able to do with .exe's)

I thought .NET Core was supposed to replace .NET Framework, is this not true?